# Saving valid moves in Negamax makes little to no difference in speed

Tags: python, algorithm, minimax, negamax

I have a normal Negamax algorithm with alpha-beta pruning which is initiated with iterative deepening (ID). I thought that to really get use of ID I save the calculated valid moves from depth 1 in a table, so next time I go for depth 2 and the same original position arrives I can just grab the valid moves from the table instead to save time. However, I find that this idea doesn't save any time at all really which makes me think:

1. I have never seen anyone do this, is it not worth it for some reason?
2. My implementation of this is wrong?
3. I am confused by how Negamax works and maybe this is impossible to do in the first place?

Here is the original iterative call, along with a snippet of the Negamax function itself:

```
self.valid_moves_history = []
for depth in range(1, s.max_search_depth):
    move, evaluation = self.negamax(gamestate, depth, -math.inf, math.inf, s.start_color)

# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------

def negamax(self, gamestate, depth, alpha, beta, color):

    if self.zobrist_key in self.valid_moves_history:
        children = self.valid_moves_history[self.zobrist_key]
    else:
        children = gamestate.get_valid_moves()
        self.valid_moves_history[key] = children

    if depth == 0 or gamestate.is_check_mate or gamestate.is_stale_mate:
        return None, e.evaluate(gamestate, depth) * color

    # Negamax loop
    max_eval = -math.inf
    for child in reversed(children):
        gamestate.make_move(child[0], child[1])
        score = -self.negamax(gamestate, depth - 1, -beta, -alpha, -color)[1]
        gamestate.unmake_move()
        if score > max_eval:
            max_eval = score
            best_move = child
        alpha = max(alpha, max_eval)
        if beta <= alpha:
            break
```

The most time consuming tasks of my complete program are distributed something like this (% of total runtime for a game):

- Calculate valid moves: 60%
- Evaluation function (medium complexity at the moment): 25%
- Negamax itself with lookups, table saves etc: 5%
- Make/unmake moves: 4%

Is it normal/reasonable for the calculating move time to be this high? This is the main reason why I thought to save valid moves in a list in the first place.

Or can someone please explain why this is a good/bad idea and what I should do instead? Thank you for any input.

Comment: Why do you think ID makes your algorithm faster? It's for cancel the search after given time or user wish and choose a move. To try the best move of the last iteration for the next does not completly compensate that you have more effort than direct search with the last depth.

Comment: @TheSlater, It definitely makes it faster, the time it takes to calculate depth 1 to N-1 is negligible compared to calculating depth N. My only move ordering is I take the best move from previous iteration as best guess, and ID is around 50% faster just from that, compared to without ID. With more move ordering it will be even more difference. I am not sure where your statement comes from.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old at this point but I think that this could still be useful to some people. The whole topic which you are talking about is called transposition tables in Minimax and you can find many links to the topic. Negamax is the same as Minimax except you do not have separate functions for the Max and Min players, and instead you just call a max function and turn it into a negative. I think it is probably more useful for you to implement move ordering first as it can double the speed of your program. You can also find a more efficient way to find valid moves to speed up the program.